# Filter rows which contain a certain string

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have to filter a data frame using as criterion those row in which is contained the string `RTB`.

I'm using `dplyr`.

```
d.del <- df %>%
  group_by(TrackingPixel) %>%
  summarise(MonthDelivery = as.integer(sum(Revenue))) %>%
  arrange(desc(MonthDelivery))
```

I know I can use the function `filter` in `dplyr` but I don't exactly how to tell it to check for the content of a string.

In particular I want to check the content in the column `TrackingPixel`. If the string contains the label `RTB` I want to remove the row from the result.

Comment: I have never used `dplyr`, but looking at the help in `?dplyr::filter` i'd suggest something like `filter(df, !grepl("RTB",TrackingPixel))` maybe?

Comment: This is actually close to what I want to achieve. The only issue is that is maintaining those string which include the label `RTB` and not showing the others.

Comment: I just put in a stealth edit, that is reversed now by adding the `!` in front of `grepl` - try it again.

Comment: Or use the `invert` and `value` arguments of `grep`. Regular expressions make working with text a thousand times easier.

Comment: @thelatemail `grepl` doesn't work on postgres for me, is this for MySQL?

Answer (score 377):

The answer to the question was already posted by the @latemail in the comments above. You can use regular expressions for the second and subsequent arguments of `filter` like this:

```
dplyr::filter(df, !grepl("RTB",TrackingPixel))
```

Since you have not provided the original data, I will add a toy example using the `mtcars` data set. Imagine you are only interested in cars produced by Mazda or Toyota.

```
mtcars$type <- rownames(mtcars)
dplyr::filter(mtcars, grepl('Toyota|Mazda', type))

   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb           type
1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      Mazda RX4
2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  Mazda RX4 Wag
3 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 Toyota Corolla
4 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1  Toyota Corona
```

If you would like to do it the other way round, namely excluding Toyota and Mazda cars, the `filter` command looks like this:

```
dplyr::filter(mtcars, !grepl('Toyota|Mazda', type))
```

Comment: what if the column name contains a space. like Tracking Pixels.

Comment: make sure you are using the filter function from the dplyr package, not the stats package

Comment: @MySchizoBuddy: If the column name contains white space, you can select the variable using backticks. Modifying the example above: `mtcars$\`my type\` <- rownames(mtcars)` and then
`mtcars %>% filter(grepl('Toyota|Mazda',  \`my type\`))`

Comment: note that this does not work when the object is a `tbl_sql` as `grepl` does not translate to sql.

Comment: option 1 is to know for sure that dplyr loaded last. option 2 is you prefix dplyr::filter.

Answer (score 251):

***Solution***

It is possible to use `str_detect` of the `stringr` package included in the `tidyverse` package. `str_detect` returns `True` or `False` as to whether the specified vector contains some specific string. It is possible to filter using this boolean value. See [Introduction to stringr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html) for details about `stringr` package.

```r
library(tidyverse)
# ─ Attaching packages ──────────────────── tidyverse 1.2.1 ─
# ✔ ggplot2 2.2.1     ✔ purrr   0.2.4
# ✔ tibble  1.4.2     ✔ dplyr   0.7.4
# ✔ tidyr   0.7.2     ✔ stringr 1.2.0
# ✔ readr   1.1.1     ✔ forcats 0.3.0
# ─ Conflicts ───────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ─
# ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
# ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()

mtcars$type <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars %>%
  filter(str_detect(type, 'Toyota|Mazda'))
# mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb           type
# 1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      Mazda RX4
# 2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  Mazda RX4 Wag
# 3 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 Toyota Corolla
# 4 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1  Toyota Corona
```

***The good things about Stringr***

We should use rather `stringr::str_detect()` than `base::grepl()`. This is because there are the following reasons.

- The functions provided by the `stringr` package start with the prefix `str_`, which makes the code easier to read.
- The first argument of the functions of `stringr` package is always the data.frame (or value), then comes the parameters.(Thank you Paolo)

```r
object <- "stringr"
# The functions with the same prefix `str_`.
# The first argument is an object.
stringr::str_count(object) # -> 7
stringr::str_sub(object, 1, 3) # -> "str"
stringr::str_detect(object, "str") # -> TRUE
stringr::str_replace(object, "str", "") # -> "ingr"
# The function names without common points.
# The position of the argument of the object also does not match.
base::nchar(object) # -> 7
base::substr(object, 1, 3) # -> "str"
base::grepl("str", object) # -> TRUE
base::sub("str", "", object) # -> "ingr"
```

***Benchmark***

The results of the benchmark test are as follows. For large dataframe, `str_detect` is faster.

```r
library(rbenchmark)
library(tidyverse)

# The data. Data expo 09. ASA Statistics Computing and Graphics 
# http://stat-computing.org/dataexpo/2009/the-data.html
df <- read_csv("Downloads/2008.csv")
print(dim(df))
# [1] 7009728      29

benchmark(
  "str_detect" = {df %>% filter(str_detect(Dest, 'MCO|BWI'))},
  "grepl" = {df %>% filter(grepl('MCO|BWI', Dest))},
  replications = 10,
  columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative", "user.self", "sys.self"))
# test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
# 2      grepl           10  16.480    1.513    16.195    0.248
# 1 str_detect           10  10.891    1.000     9.594    1.281
```

Comment: Why is stringr a better option than grep?

Comment: @CameronNemo The functions provided by the `stringr` package start with the prefix str_, which makes the code easier to read. In recent modern R code, it is recommended to use stringr.

Comment: I think this is a very personal preference and I do agree with @CameronNemo that `base R` is as good as `stringr`. If you would provide us with some 'hard facts' such as benchmarking, and not only stating "it is recommended" (Who does recommend it?) , this would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: An other reason is the consistency in the tidyverse framework: the first argument of a function is always the data.frame (or value), then comes the parameters.

Comment: Just stumbled into this post, I know it's an old discussion but just in case someone else gets here: one reason one may prefer `str_detect` over `grepl` is that if there's a missing value `str_detect` will return `NA`, while `grepl` will return `FALSE`, which can be misleading.

Comment: if I do without filter like:  " mtcars %>% str_detect(type, 'Toyota|Mazda') " I receive Error in type(pattern) : object 'type' not found. Why do I not get an vector with TRUE FALSE ?

Comment: Add rowwise() is the solution to receive a vector with TRUE FALSE. See post below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659198/detect-multiple-strings-with-dplyr-and-stringr

Comment: @Keiku Is it possible to use `str_detect` to directly detect strings in the rownames without adding these as a new column in the data frame?

Answer (score 54):

This answer similar to others, but using preferred `stringr::str_detect` and dplyr `rownames_to_column`.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("type") %>% 
  filter(stringr::str_detect(type, 'Toyota|Mazda') )

#>             type  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1      Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2  Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3 Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> 4  Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
```

Created on 2018-06-26 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 21):

Here's another `dplyr` solution, using `filter(if_all/if_any)`. The advantage is that you can easily extend **to more than one column**. Below showing how to filter for rows with a given string in *any* column, using `diamonds` as example, looking for the string "V".

---

**edit** to reflect changes in the dplyr syntax (>=dplyr vs. 1.0.10). Previously using `across` (now deprecated) and even before that `filter_all` or `filter_any` (superseded).

---

**Removing rows where *any column* fulfils a condition**

```r
library(dplyr)

## with if_any
ggplot2::diamonds %>%
  ## NB ! needs to come before if_any
  filter(!if_any(everything(), ~ grepl('V', .))) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 10
#>   carat cut     color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <ord>   <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  0.23 Ideal   E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
#> 2  0.21 Premium E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#> 3  0.31 Good    J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
#> 4  0.3  Good    J     SI1      64      55   339  4.25  4.28  2.73
#> 5  0.22 Premium F     SI1      60.4    61   342  3.88  3.84  2.33
#> 6  0.31 Ideal   J     SI2      62.2    54   344  4.35  4.37  2.71

## or with if_all
ggplot2::diamonds %>%
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~ !grepl('V', .))) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 10
#>   carat cut     color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <ord>   <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  0.23 Ideal   E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
#> 2  0.21 Premium E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#> 3  0.31 Good    J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
#> 4  0.3  Good    J     SI1      64      55   339  4.25  4.28  2.73
#> 5  0.22 Premium F     SI1      60.4    61   342  3.88  3.84  2.33
#> 6  0.31 Ideal   J     SI2      62.2    54   344  4.35  4.37  2.71
```

**Filtering for rows where *any column* fulfils a condition**

```
## The new syntax makes it also easy to positively filter rows 
## where one columns fulfils a condition
ggplot2::diamonds %>%
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ grepl('V',.))) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 10
#>   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  0.23 Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#> 2  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
#> 3  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
#> 4  0.24 Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
#> 5  0.26 Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
#> 6  0.22 Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
```

Comment: Do you know why `diamonds %>% filter(across(everything(), ~grepl('V', .)))` returns an empty tibble? I would think simply removing the `!` would return all rows with a V in any column?

Comment: @DylanRussell sorry for the late answer. I thought this was obvious - using everything means that you're looking for rows that have "V" in ALL columns.

Comment: ~ !grepl what is the use of ~ and ! could you please tell me ?

Comment: I think ~ is a function call when applying to all data

Comment: This might be updated using `if_any()` or `if_all()`

Answer (score 1):

A further option based on [Akruns' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44544616/7941188) - create a logical vector with rowSums and subset. Only with base R. This is in particular then useful and elegant, when the column contains exactly the value that we are looking for. (or if you can create a two-dimensional array with a simple conditional statement like below: `df1 == "no_data"`)

```r
## this is very easy when the expected value is EXACTLY the string
df1 <- structure(list(time = c("1:00", "2:00", "no_data", "3:00"), speed = c("30", "no_data", "no_data", "50"), wheels = c("no_data", "18", "no_data", "18")), .Names = c("time", "speed", "wheels"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
df1[rowSums(df1 == "no_data") == 0, , drop = FALSE]
#>   time speed wheels
#> 4 3:00    50     18

## it's a bit more verbose when the expected value just CONTAINS the string
mtcars$type <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars[rowSums(apply(mtcars, 2, \(x) grepl('Toyota|Mazda', x))) > 0, , drop = FALSE] |> head()
#>                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#> Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#>                          type
#> Mazda RX4           Mazda RX4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag   Mazda RX4 Wag
#> Toyota Corolla Toyota Corolla
#> Toyota Corona   Toyota Corona
```