# Working with non numeric data

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm currently working with dplyr and struggling to subset variables based on specific data.

I need to subset the iris data to contain only the species virginica, and within that, they should all have a sepal length of more than 6.

I've tried the filter and select function and am getting nowhere as they want numeric values while I'm working with words.

Comment: Doen't this work? `iris %>% filter(Species == "virginica" & Sepal.Length > 6)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please provide your code, even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering row which contains a certain string using dplyr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filtering-row-which-contains-a-certain-string-using-dplyr)

Comment: thanks, that code has worked great!