# Remove row if any column contains a specific string

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out the best approach in R to remove rows that contain a specific string, in my case 'no_data'.

I have data from an outside source that imputes na's with 'no_data'

an example is this:

```
 time  |speed  |wheels
1:00   |30     |no_data
2:00   |no_data|18
no_data|no_data|no_data
3:00   |50     |18
```

I want to go through the data and remove each row containing this 'no_data' string in any column. I have had a lot of trouble figuring this out. I have tried an sapply, filter, grep and combinations of the three. I am by no means an r expert so it could just be me incorrectly using these. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filter-rows-which-contain-a-certain-string/49858451#49858451

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter rows which contain a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filter-rows-which-contain-a-certain-string)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` to create a logical `vector` and subset based on it

```
df1[rowSums(df1 == "no_data")==0, , drop = FALSE]
#   time speed wheels
#4 3:00    50     18
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(time = c("1:00", "2:00", "no_data", "3:00"), speed = c("30", 
"no_data", "no_data", "50"), wheels = c("no_data", "18", "no_data", 
"18")), .Names = c("time", "speed", "wheels"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I m getting some weird results when I do `df1 == 'no_data'`. Did you read the data frame from OP or did you create it yourself?

Comment: @Sotos Updated the data I used

Comment: When I try this method, i get a "string is not in a standard unambiguous format" I assume this is because I have a mix of char,int,and num variables in the real data set. I failed to express that in my example...

Comment: @lentz Could you please check the `str(yourdata)`  Here I have `character` class.  If it is factor, convert to `character`

Comment: I believe the problem was due to a few `POSIXct` formats I had in the data. converted to `character`

Answer (score 9):

**edit** update to the `filter(if_all/if_any)` syntax (dplyr vs. 1.0.10), formerly using `across` (now deprecated) and even before that `filter_all` or `filter_any` (superseded).

Here a `dplyr` option: (using Akrun's data)

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- structure(list(time = c("1:00", "2:00", "no_data", "3:00"), speed = c("30", "no_data", "no_data", "50"), wheels = c("no_data", "18", "no_data", "18")), .Names = c("time", "speed", "wheels"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

## with if_any
df1 %>% filter(if_any(everything(), ~ grepl("no_data", .)))
#>      time   speed  wheels
#> 1    1:00      30 no_data
#> 2    2:00 no_data      18
#> 3 no_data no_data no_data

## or with if_all
df1 %>% filter(if_all(everything(), ~ !grepl("no_data", .)))
#>   time speed wheels
#> 1 3:00    50     18

## to GET all rows that fulfil condition, use
df1 %>% filter(if_any(everything(), ~ grepl("no_data", .)))
#>      time   speed  wheels
#> 1    1:00      30 no_data
#> 2    2:00 no_data      18
#> 3 no_data no_data no_data
```

Answer (score 8):

You can read the data using `na.strings = 'no_data'` to set them as `NA` and then simply omit NAs (or take `complete.cases`), i.e. (Using @akrun's data set)

```
d1 <- read.table(text = 'time   speed  wheels
 1    1:00      30 no_data
            2    2:00 no_data      18
            3 no_data no_data no_data
            4    3:00      50      18', na.strings = 'no_data', h=TRUE)

d1[complete.cases(d1),]
#  time speed wheels
#4 3:00    50     18

#OR

na.omit(d1)
#  time speed wheels
#4 3:00    50     18
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. I couldn't get it directly from OP data as some elements were 'no_data', others ' no_data', and others remain a mystery :)

Answer (score 3):

akrun answer is quick, correct and simply as much is it can :)
however if you like to make your life more complex you can also do:

```
dat
     time   speed  wheels
1    1:00      30 no_data
2    2:00 no_data      18
3 no_data no_data no_data
4    3:00      50      18

dat$new <- apply(dat[,1:3], 1, function(x) any(x %in% c("no_data")))
dat <- dat[!(dat$new==TRUE),]
dat$new <- NULL

dat
  time speed wheels
4 3:00    50     18
```