# How do I subset a data frame by row for ALL columns

Tags: r

This seems like a very simple problem but I am unable to find a solution anywhere online. I want to subset a data frame to rows for which any column contains the string "string". This is how I want to subset the data:

```
subset <- df[which(df$V1 == 'string' | df$V2 == 'string' | df$V3=='string'),]
```

But my frame has many columns and it is very inefficient to list all of them. Is there a more efficient way to select rows for which ANY column contains 'string'?

Comment: Avoid names like `subset`. Not always important due to the presence of IDEs, but might spend too much time figuring out what went wrong if you ever need to use the function `subset`.  Please also provide a sample of your data.

Comment: Similar post, just with logic of *dropping* those rows instead of *keeping* them: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44544596/5325862

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` to create a create a logical vector for subsetting the rows

```
nm1 <- paste0("V", 1:3)
df[rowSums(df[nm1] == "string") >  0,]
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you!

Comment: Probably want `paste0`, not `patse0`

Comment: Cool, sorry, I am a stack noob. It worked.