# How to subtract specific rows to a part of a dataframe based on the value of a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm quite a new R user and it would be awesome if someone could help me to figure this out!

I have data looking like this:

```
eDNA.data 

    Sample     Extraction_batch    Species 1     Species 2    Specie3    Species 4
    CH15_25    CH_1                0             39           10         0
    CH15_89    CH_2                11            0            55         0
    CH15_56    CH_1                0             0            0          13
    CH15_16    CH_1                27            12           0          7
    CH15_21    CH_2                0             0            2          0
    CH15_negA  CH_1                0             1            0          0
    CH15_negB  CH_2                0             0            2          1
    IQ15_10    IQ_1                8             67           43         0
    IQ15_64    IQ_1                17            0            24         6
    IQ15_17    IQ_2                5             0            0          0
    IQ15_87    IQ_1                0             11           7          0
    IQ15_negA  IQ_1                1             0            0          0
    IQ15_negB  IQ_2                0             0            1          1
```

I have 218 species in total and a lot more samples (148 in total) which are DNA extractions. The `Extraction_batch` column correspond to which extraction the samples belong (because I could only do 24 at the time) and **for each extraction batch there is one negative control corresponding**. Negative control are blank samples to see if contamination occured during the extraction.

I would like to subtract the row of the negatives controls (ex. IQ15_negA) to all the rows corresponding to the same value in the column `Extraction_batch`. So I could obtain a new dataframe contamination free.

How can I do this in R?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering row which contains a certain string using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filtering-row-which-contains-a-certain-string-using-dplyr)

Comment: some verbs / vocabulary to help you search for related questions & solve your problem: you're trying to group by `Extraction_batch` and normalize your other columns relative to a specific row within each group. It may also be easier/more natural (though not at first glance) to separate the "negative" rows into their own `data.frame`, separate from this table. You can then join the "negative" table to the normal table and subtract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider subsetting dataframe by *neg* values, then merge *neg_df* and *clean_df* together for a column-wise subtractions:

```
# CREATE SAMPLE STUB NAME
df$Sample_stub <- substr(df$Sample, 1, 4)

# FILTER FOR NEG ROWS, DROP SAMPLE, RENAME SPECIES COLS WITH NEG_ PREFIX
neg_df <- transform(df[grepl("neg", df$Sample),], Sample = NULL)
names(neg_df)[grep("Species", names(neg_df))] <- paste0("Neg_", names(neg_df)[grep("Species", names(neg_df))])

# FILTER FOR CLEAN ROWS
clean_df <- df[!grepl("neg", df$Sample),]

# MERGE BOTH SETS, DROP STUB NAME
final_df <- merge(clean_df, neg_df, by=c("Sample_stub", "Extraction_batch"))[-1]

# BLOCKWISE (MULTI-COLUMN) SUBTRACTION
final_df[, grep("^Species", names(final_df))] <- final_df[, grep("^Species", names(final_df))] - 
                                                 final_df[, grep("^Neg", names(final_df))]
# REMOVE NEG SPECIES COLUMNS
final_df[, grep("^Neg", names(final_df))] <- NULL

final_df
#   Extraction_batch  Sample Species1 Species2 Species3 Species4
# 1             CH_1 CH15_25        0       38       10        0
# 2             CH_1 CH15_56        0       -1        0       13
# 3             CH_1 CH15_16       27       11        0        7
# 4             CH_2 CH15_89       11        0       53       -1
# 5             CH_2 CH15_21        0        0        0       -1
# 6             IQ_1 IQ15_10        7       67       43        0
# 7             IQ_1 IQ15_64       16        0       24        6
# 8             IQ_1 IQ15_87       -1       11        7        0
# 9             IQ_2 IQ15_17        5        0       -1       -1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've tried several times your script but it seems there is a problem at the second step `neg_df <- setNames(transform(df[grepl("neg", df$Sample),], Sample = NULL),
                   c("Sample_stub", "Extraction_batch", paste0("Neg_", names(neg_df)[grep("Species", names(neg_df))])))` an error message appears  `Error in paste0("Neg_", names(neg_df)[grep("Species", names(neg_df))]) : 
  object 'neg_df' not found`

Comment: See update where subsetting rows and renaming columns are done in two different lines.

Comment: It's almost working! After merging the `clean_df` and the `neg_df` the species names are duplicated and appear like **species1.x** and **species1.y** so at the blockwise subtraction the column of the neg_df is not subtracted :/

Comment: You did not successfully rename as it should have avoided the name collision as it intended. I'm seeing now your *species* is lower case unlike your post above. R is case sensitive!

Comment: I've changed the species names and it's working perfectly now! Thanks a lot!