# Filtering rows based on "complex" strings in a column R/dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am able to filter my dataset using the strings in a particular column, here's a sample dataset and how I did it.

```
ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
String = c("Y N No", "Y", "Y No", "Y N")
df = data.frame(ID, String)
```

The problem is - I want to only pick the IDs that have N in them - or - IDs that don't have N in them.

```
df_2 <- dpylr::filter(df, !grepl('N', String)) 

Output: [2]  [Y]
```

This will filter out the ID's with N, but it also removes ALL cases of N (including those that have 'No'. I'm new to R so I apologize if this is just me not understanding the syntax - but I cannot figure this out.

I could also try parsing out the string into individual columns, then selecting based on that - I need to do this anyway for later analysis. Below is the code that I use to achieve this.

```
df_2 <- df%>%mutate(String=gsub("\\b([A-Za-z]+)\\b","\\11",String),
          name=str_extract_all(String,"[A-Za-z]+"),
          value=str_extract_all(String,"\\d+"))%>%
unnest()%>%spread(name,value,fill=0)
```

This gives me

```
Output: 
ID<chr>  String<chr>   N<chr>  No <chr>   Y<chr>
1         Y1 N1 No1      1        1         1
2         Y1             0        0         1
3         Y1 No1         0        1         1
4         Y1 N1          1        0         1
```

This way I could just select my rows based on whether or not N is zero or one - however, R doesn't like when I do this and I do not understand why.

Thank you for any help you could offer.

**EDIT: Here is a sample of my actual data. I might have over simplified in my question.**

```
m/z             Column

241             C15 H22 O Na                
265             C15 H15 N5 
301             C16 H22 O4 Na 
335             C19 H20 O4 Na           
441             C26 H42 O4 Na
```

My goal is to filter out all of the N's in Column (They range from N, N1, N4, etc)

Comment: *"however, R doesn't like when I do this"* Can you be more specific. What "doesn't [R] like"? Is there an error? What error? I can reproduce your output `df_2` just fine -- without any errors.

Comment: Does `df %>% filter(grepl("N\\s", String))` work? Here you match `"N"` plus a white-space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering row which contains a certain string using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filtering-row-which-contains-a-certain-string-using-dplyr)

Comment: `df %>% filter(grepl("\\bN\\b", String))`

Comment: perhaps the patterns should be `"N(\\d|$)"` to allow "N" or " blah N" to be matched?

Comment: Maurits - I think it's just because I do not understand the syntax. @Onyambu how would I do this to ignore N? Or multiple characters within the string?

Comment: to ignore N `df %>% filter(!grepl("\\bN\\b", String))`

Comment: @Onyambu Hi - That indeed works for my sample set, but I might have over simplified in my question. See my edit for a small set of my real data - the strings are a bit more complicated and these functions won't work for it :/

Comment: Which N do you want to keep?

Comment: @Onyambu I want to be able to either keep N(digits) or ignore N(digits) (No or Na doesn't have any relevance to me).

Comment: @Ragstock To keep `"N"` plus `>0` digits: `df %>% filter(grepl("N\\d+", String))`

Comment: @MauritsEvers How to make this work if there is no digit? Sorry when I said digits, I assume 0 is one as well - or the absence of it.

Comment: @Ragstock Do you mean `df %>% filter(grepl("(N\\d+|N\\s)", String))`? This keeps entries that contain `"N"` plus *either* a digit *or* a white-space. Negate if you want to exclude.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Wow okay this worked - amazing - I need to figure out this grepl function and that syntax. I can also do this with multiple characters ! Thank you - updating solution to original post.

Comment: The syntax is called regular expression (often regexp or regex in short); [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) is good starting point for reading:-)

Comment: basically if you have something like this `x=c("N","Na","N1","2N","2Na","N2a")`and you don't need the N's what should be your expected results??

Comment: Don't add a solution as an edit to the question. Instead, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
String = c("Y N No", "Y", "Y No", "Y N")
df = data.frame(ID, String)
df %>% filter(!grepl("(N\\d+|N\\s)", String))

Output: [Y] [Y No]
```

This answer by @MauritsEvers also works for the more complicated dataset in the second paragraph - where digits that may also come after N (like N2 or N10) will also be included in the argument. Remove "!" for including "N".

Answer (score 0):

I think your second approach is the way to go, especially if you going to split the columns for downstream analysis. It also (imo) meets "tidy" requirements. I also suggest standardising the `String` variable. Yes/Y, No/N are not acceptable.

The `tidyr` package has a two nice function for this `separate` and `gather`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
String = c("Y N No", "Y", "Y No", "Y N")
String <- gsub(pattern = "No", "N", String)
df = data.frame(ID, String)

#Separate the String var
df_sep <- separate(df, col = String, into = c("R1", "R2", "R3"), sep = " ", extra = "merge")
#gather the columns
df_gat <- gather(df_sep, Cols, StrValue, R1:R3, -ID) 
#filter
filter(df_gat, StrValue == "N" | StrValue != "N")
```

Here is my modified answer:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Separate the String var
df_sep <- separate(df, col = Column, into = c("E1", "E2", "E3", "E4"), sep = " ", extra = "merge")
#gather the columns, long data format
gather(df_sep, Cols, Element, E1:E4, -m.z) %>% select(m.z, Element) -> df_gat
#filter
filter(df_gat, !grepl("^N$|N\\d", df_gat$Element))
```

It produces a long dataset that works well with the filter function. Your data previously was wide (kinda). I suggest changing the symbol of sodium to something else, you may run into trouble if Na (sodium) is converted to `NA`.

Comment: I'm sorry but my actual dataset is much more complicated than this one (N and No were supposed to denote different things - my bad!). Would I use the separate and gather function rather than the one I have in my second paragraph? I'm not sure I quite understand the output this gave me..

Comment: Right... real data is AWLAYS helpful. First of all `Na` values are actual Not Available or does `Na` stand for something? Going to modify my answer to answer with new data

Comment: Na stands for Sodium - N stands for Nitrogen. I got knocked down for using real data (too complicated) in another post so I tried to simplify, but it looks like I went too far with it here.

Comment: Odd, I always prefer real data as long as it's simply to work with! It looks like you're working was mass spec data, so I can see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `sub` to substitute `""` for any pattern matching `"N(\\d{1,3}|\\s|$)"`, meaning "N" followed by one of 1-3 digits or space or end of string.

I don't think you wnat to use filtering since as I understood the English description, you wanted to remove specific patterns from with character values. I was imagining that these were chemical symbols and that `N` was nitrogen and `Na` was sodium.

Comment: Not quite sure how to make this one work. Using the initial, simple example, I would do `df %>% sub("N(\\d{1,3}|\\s|$)", " ") ` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the dply route would be, with base R just: `sub(patt="N(\\d{1,3}|\\s|$)", repl=" ", df$String) #
[1] "Y  No" "Y"     "Y No"  "Y  "`