# Grouping Like Variables in Tibbles for R

Tags: r

Working on my second project for R.  I'm trying to create some variable groups using `dplyr`, but I'm not sure what the heck I'm doing here.

I'm working with financial data and among the categories, there are several different forms of travel, listed as such:

Travel - Gas, Travel - Airfare, Travel - Subway...

I want to create a new `tibble` that groups all the Travel subtypes as one Travel subgroup. Is there a good way to do this?

I've been trying to use the `dplyr` `filter` function to no effect so far.

Sorry, I was really tired and forgot to put an example up

I have data that's like this:

```
Month - Year - Category - Amount
01 - 2016 - "Travel- Air" - 247.02
01 - 2016 - "Travel- Car" - 29.04
01 - 2016 - "Retail"      - 45.00
03 - 2017 - "Travel - Air" - 253.60
```

I'm trying to group things so that all the transactions of one type in a particular month/year are summed together like this:

```
Total_Category_Transactions_Month <- Total_Transactions %>%
    group_by(month,Year,Category) %>%
    summarize(monthly = sum(Amount))
```

But after looking at my data, there are just way too many things that are grouped up as "Travel - foo."  I'd like to keep that detail for later to analyze, but for the big scale picture, I want to see if I can lump all those Travel expenses as one thing each month.

The Output should end up being:

```
   Month - Year - Category - Amount
    01  - 2016  - "Travel"  - 276.06
    01  - 2016  - "Retail"  - 45.00
    03  - 2017  - "Travel"  - 253.60
```

Where all the subtypes of category Travel_Foo from the same month and year are added together into one category just called Travel

Comment: Use regular expression like `stringr::str_detect` or `grep`. eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filtering-row-which-contains-a-certain-string-using-dplyr

Comment: Your question is unclear, please read and edit your question according to: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post for clarity.

Comment: I struggle to understand what you're trying to do, and your sample data is not quite clear to me (the `-` symbol seems to denote a column separator but can also be part of the strings in column `Category`?). These ambiguities can be avoided if you use `dput` to provide (part of your) data; also include your expected output for the sample data you give.

Comment: I've edited again.  This will teach me to post stuff while I'm tired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `tidyr::separate`

```
df %>%
    separate(Category, into = c("Category"), extra = "drop") %>%
    group_by(Month, Year, Category) %>%
    summarise(Amount = sum(Amount)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    as.data.frame()
#  Month Year Category Amount
#1     1 2016   Retail  45.00
#2     1 2016   Travel 276.06
#3     3 2017   Travel 253.60
```

Note that the `as.data.frame()` is not really necessary here. I've only included it to show that the resulting `Amount`s are the ones from your expected output (the `tibble`s don't print the same number of decimal places).

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Month  Year  Category  Amount
01  2016  'Travel- Air'  247.02
01  2016  'Travel- Car'  29.04
01  2016  'Retail'       45.00
03  2017  'Travel - Air'  253.60", header = T)
```