# i want to find and delete rows that contain certain data in r language?

Tags: r

a-      b-        c-          d
1-     Aman-     cake-       red
2-Manish-cookie-blue
3-Anish-cola-black
a-b-c-d
4-Pankaj-kite-green
5-Anuj-jet-brown
a-b-c-d
6-Ami-goat-white

This all data is in single data.frame. I want to find the location of the values (a   b   c   d) other than the header, and ten i want to delete those values from the data.frame.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter rows which contain a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filter-rows-which-contain-a-certain-string)

Comment: yes it did the work.thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(!str_detect(column_name, "a-b-c-d"))
```

Comment: a b c d are header values that are copied inside the table multiple times.they are not single character.

Comment: So? Could you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: yoour answer is correct bu instead of all "a-b-c-d" jst including "a" is enough to remove the whole row.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are easier ways of doing what the question asks for, but the following works.

```
library(dplyr)

pattern <- paste(names(df1), collapse = "|")

df1 %>%
  mutate_all(~(stringr::str_detect(., pattern = pattern))) %>%
  mutate(ok = rowSums(.) != ncol(.)) %>%
  select(ok) %>%
  bind_cols(df1, .) %>%
  dplyr::filter(ok) %>%
  select(-ok)
#  a      b      c     d
#1 1   Aman   cake   red
#2 2 Manish cookie  blue
#3 3  Anish   cola black
#4 4 Pankaj   kite green
#5 5   Anuj    jet brown
#6 6    Ami   goat white
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
a- b- c- d
1- Aman- cake- red
2-Manish-cookie-blue
3-Anish-cola-black
a-b-c-d
4-Pankaj-kite-green
5-Anuj-jet-brown
a-b-c-d
6-Ami-goat-white
", header = TRUE, sep = "-")
```