# Translating filter_all(any_vars()) to filter(across())

Tags: r, dplyr

On updating [my own answer to another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49858451/7941188), I wasn't able to come up with a good solution to replace the last example (see below). The idea is to get all rows where *any* column contains a certain string, in my example "V".

```r
library(tidyverse)

#get all rows where any column contains 'V'
diamonds %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(grepl('V',.))) %>%
  head
#> # A tibble: 6 x 10
#>   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#> 2 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
#> 3 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
#> 4 0.24  Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
#> 5 0.26  Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
#> 6 0.22  Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49


# this does naturally not give the desired output! 
diamonds %>%
  filter(across(everything(), ~ grepl('V', .))) %>%
  head
#> # A tibble: 0 x 10
```

I found a thread where the [poster ponders over similar stuff](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-replace-retired-all-vars-and-any-vars-using-across/53102), but applying a similar logic on grepl does not work.

```
### don't run, this is ugly and does not work
diamonds %>%
  rowwise %>%
  filter(any(grepl("V", across(everything())))) %>%
  head
```

Comment: If I check the dataset, it is `ordered` ie. factor column and BTW, you need `c_across`, but still it would have an issue with the types

Comment: This is very difficult, because the example shows that you want to filter data from _all_ columns when _any_ of them satisfies the condition (i.e. you want a _union_). That's done with `filter_all()` and `any_vars()`. While `filter(across(everything(), ...))` filters out from all columns when all of them satisfy the condition (i.e. this is a _intersection_, quite opposite of what you originaly wanted). Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @PetrKajzar That's why I am asking this question! If you have an idea, please post it :)

Comment: @Tjebo Wow, nice question then! OK, I tried to post some idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is very difficult, because the example shows that you want to filter data from *all* columns when *any* of them meets the condition (i.e. you want a *union*). That's done with `filter_all()` and `any_vars()`.

While `filter(across(everything(), ...))` filters out from *all* columns when *all* of them meet the condition (i.e. this is a *intersection*, quite opposite of the previous).

To convert it from *intersection* to the *union* (i.e. to get again rows where *any* of the columns meet the condition), you probably need to check the row sum for that:

```
diamonds %>%
   filter(rowSums(across(everything(), ~grepl("V", .x))) > 0)
```

It will sum all the `TRUE`s that appear in the row, i.e. if there is at least one value meeting the condition, that row sum will be `> 0` and will be shown.

I'm sorry for `across()` is not the very first child of `filter()`, but it's at least some idea how to do that. :-)

---

**Evaluation:**

Using @TimTeaFan's method to check that:

```
 identical(
     {diamonds %>%
         filter_all(any_vars(grepl('V',.)))
     }, 
     {diamonds %>%
         filter(rowSums(across(everything(), ~grepl("V", .x))) > 0)
     }
 )
 #> [1] TRUE
```

**Benchmark:**

As per our discussion under TimTeaFan's answer, here is a comparison, surprisingly, all solutions have a similar time:

```r
library(tidyverse)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  filter_all = {diamonds %>%
      filter_all(any_vars(grepl('V',.)))}, 
  purrr_reduce = {diamonds %>%
      filter(across(everything(), ~ grepl('V', .)) %>% purrr::reduce(`|`))},
  base_reduce = {diamonds %>%
      filter(across(everything(), ~ grepl('V', .)) %>% Reduce(`|`, .))},
  rowsums = {diamonds %>%
      filter(rowSums(across(everything(), ~grepl("V", .x))) > 0)},
  times = 100L,
  check = "identical"
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>          expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>    filter_all 295.7235 302.1311 309.6455 305.0491 310.0335 449.3619   100
#>  purrr_reduce 297.8220 302.4411 310.2829 306.2929 312.2278 461.0194   100
#>   base_reduce 298.5033 303.6170 309.4147 306.1839 312.3518 409.5273   100
#>       rowsums 295.3863 301.0281 307.8517 305.3142 309.4793 372.8867   100
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You might add a note about `na.rm = TRUE` in the rowSums function to account for missing values. This tripped me up.

Answer (score 3):

This is the equivalent to the `filter_all` call you posted. However, @akrun is totally correct to point out, that it should be converted to character first. Nevertheless, this also holds true for your `filter_all` statement.

The idea is to use `across(everything(), ~ grepl('V', .))` to get the whole data.frame transformed into columns of `TRUE` and `FALSE` regarding `grepl('V', .)`. However, `filter` needs a vector, or a data.frame with one column so we transform it by using reduce(`|`). It combines the first two columns with `|` then the result of this call with the third column and so on, until the original data.frame has one column with `TRUE` and `FALSE` which can then be used to filter the rows.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

diamonds %>%
  filter(across(everything(), ~ grepl('V', .)) %>% purrr::reduce(`|`)) %>% 
  head
#> # A tibble: 6 x 10
#>   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#> 2 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
#> 3 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
#> 4 0.24  Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
#> 5 0.26  Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
#> 6 0.22  Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49

identical({diamonds %>%
            filter_all(any_vars(grepl('V',.)))}, 
          {diamonds %>%
            filter(across(everything(), ~ grepl('V', .)) %>% purrr::reduce(`|`))
            })
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Man, it took me a while to recognize the backticks as backticks! That's a real cool use of reduce and very clever!! However, I find @petrkajzar's solution with rowSums very elegant (no need for call to another package, and somewhat shorter in code, and kind of immediately intuitive, but I haven't benchmarked it!)

Comment: I like the rowSums approach too, it’s more concise and it should also be faster.

Comment: TimTeaFan, what a nice use of reduce, good approach! @Tjebo I have tried to benchmark that, see my updated answer. Suprisingly, none of the solutions is significantly faster than the others! :-)

Comment: @PetrKajzar yet, your solution is still fastest! I think this may become more visible with lot bigger data :)

Answer (score 1):

Some of the columns were `ordered` and it will affect with `c_across`.  Instead, if we convert to `character` class and then do the `grepl` it should work

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
diamonds %>%
    head %>% 
    mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character)) %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    filter(any(grepl("V", c_across(where(is.character)))))
# A tibble: 3 x 10
# Rowwise: 
#  carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#  <dbl> <chr>     <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#2 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
#3 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun! Not sure I like this change in this case... :( I find filter_all somehow much more concise. Maybe worth an issue on github

Comment: @Tjebo I think this is under development and at least 2 or 3 questions in the recent days have a similar issue.  Probably they will fix on create a new feature