# Filter row based on a string condition, dplyr filter, contains

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, contains

I want to filter a dataframe using dplyr contains() and filter. Must be simple, right? The examples I've seen use base R grepl which sort of defeats the object. Here's a simple dataframe:

```
site_type <- c('Urban','Rural','Rural Background','Urban Background','Roadside','Kerbside')
df <- data.frame(row_id, site_type)
df <- as.tibble(df)
df
```

Now I want to filter the dataframe by all rows where site.type contains the string background.
I can find the string directly if I know the unique values of site_type:

`filtered_df <- filter(df, site_type == 'Urban Background')`

But I want to do something like:

`filtered_df <- filter(df, site_type(contains('background', match_case = False)))`

Any ideas how to do that? Can dplyr helper `contains` only be used with columns and not rows?

Comment: Omitted the row_id in the df by mistake, row_id = c(id1, id2, id3 ...) You get the picture :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `contains` function in dplyr is a **select helper**. It's purpose is to help when using the `select` function, and the `select` function is focused on selecting columns not rows. See documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0/topics/select_helpers).

`filter` is the intended mechanism for selecting rows. The function you are probably looking for is `grepl` which does pattern matching for text.

So the solution you are looking for is probably:

```r
filtered_df <- filter(df, grepl("background", site_type, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

I suspect that `contains` is mostly a wrapper applying `grepl` to the column names. So the logic is very similar.

References:

- [grep R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/grep)
- [high rated question applying exactly this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filter-rows-which-contain-a-certain-string)

Comment: Thanks for the answer - that's what I feared, and is a bit of a disappointment (sorry dplyr) but really appreciate you helping me out!

Comment: grepl only selects the first element of the list to match. This should not be the accepted answer

Comment: @Amar your critique is unclear to me. `grepl` works on vectors and will return all the matches in the column. Were you wanting to search for more than one keyword? (for example `'back'` or `'ground'`) If so, this can be done by modifying the search term passed to `grepl`.

Comment: Apologies you are correct and I am wrong. I had the `pattern` and `x` switched around. `grepl` is not vectorised for the `pattern`, so it will silently choose the first element in a `pattern` list but that is not what the question was asking. Again, apologies!

Comment: Not a problem. Thank you for clarifying @Amar