# How to remove certain junk values from a column in a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a column called Region in a data frame which is of character type. It has certain junk values as below which I want to remove:

"#VALUE!","10.1","10.2","138","145","161"

But when I try to remove using things like subset they don't get removed as follows:

```
subset(pro_202_data,Region != c("#VALUE!","10.1","10.2","138","145","161"))
```

I have tried using only `!=` but that also doesn't work.

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter rows which contain a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filter-rows-which-contain-a-certain-string)

Comment: Can you give a sample data frame with `dput()`?

Comment: To match more than one value you need to use `%in%`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer, I've created a dataframe with what you've provided and tried to filter out first two rows, you can try similarly for your entire dataframe.

```
> pro_202_data
   Region
1 #VALUE!
2    10.1
3    10.2
4     138
5     145
6     161
> subset(pro_202_data, !(Region %in% c("#VALUE!","10.1")))
  Region
3   10.2
4    138
5    145
6    161
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subset like this:

Single vector:

```
x <- c("#VALUE!","10.1","10.2","138","145","161")
x[!x=="#VALUE!"]
[1] "10.1" "10.2" "138"  "145"  "161"
```

Dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Region = c("#VALUE!","10.1","10.2","138","145","161"), stringsAsFactors = F
)

df[!df$Region=="#VALUE!",]
[1] "10.1" "10.2" "138"  "145"  "161"
```

Note the addition of the `,`to select all columns of the dataframe.