# Combining filter, across, and starts_with to string search across columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

This is very similar to [the answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49858451), but I cannot figure out why starts_with does not work:

```
diamonds %>% 
    filter(across(clarity, ~ grepl('^S', .))) %>% 
    head

# A tibble: 6 x 10
  carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
  <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
3  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
4  0.26 Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
5  0.3  Good      J     SI1      64      55   339  4.25  4.28  2.73
6  0.22 Premium   F     SI1      60.4    61   342  3.88  3.84  2.33
```

```
diamonds %>%
  filter(across(starts_with("c"),~grepl("^S" ,.))) %>% 
  head

# A tibble: 0 x 10
# ... with 10 variables: carat <dbl>, cut <ord>, color <ord>, clarity <ord>, depth <dbl>, table <dbl>,
#   price <int>, x <dbl>, y <dbl>, z <dbl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### dplyr before 1.0.4

```r
diamonds %>%
  filter(rowSums(across(starts_with("c"),~grepl("^S" ,.))) > 0) 
# A tibble: 22,259 x 10
#    carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#    <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
#  2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#  3  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
#  4  0.26 Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
#  5  0.3  Good      J     SI1      64      55   339  4.25  4.28  2.73
#  6  0.22 Premium   F     SI1      60.4    61   342  3.88  3.84  2.33
#  7  0.31 Ideal     J     SI2      62.2    54   344  4.35  4.37  2.71
#  8  0.2  Premium   E     SI2      60.2    62   345  3.79  3.75  2.27
#  9  0.3  Ideal     I     SI2      62      54   348  4.31  4.34  2.68
# 10  0.3  Good      J     SI1      63.4    54   351  4.23  4.29  2.7 
# # ... with 22,249 more rows
```

How to figure this out or confirm it:

```r
diamonds %>%
  filter({browser(); across(starts_with("c"),~grepl("^S" ,.)); })
# Called from: mask$eval_all_filter(dots, env_filter)
# debug at #1: across(starts_with("c"), ~grepl("^S", .))

across(starts_with("c"), ~ grepl("^S" , .))
# # A tibble: 53,940 x 4
#    carat cut   color clarity
#    <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>  
#  1 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE   
#  2 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE   
#  3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  
#  4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  
#  5 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE   
#  6 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  
#  7 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  
#  8 FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE   
#  9 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  
# 10 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  
# # ... with 53,930 more rows
```

To me, it seems apparent that one would want any row with at least one `TRUE` (or perhaps all, but I'll assume "any" for now). Since this is a frame of logicals, we can use `rowSums`, which should sum falses as 0 and trues as 1, so

```r
head(rowSums(across(starts_with("c"), ~ grepl("^S" , .))) > 0)
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

which is a single vector of logicals, one per row, which is what `dplyr::filter` ultimately wants/needs.

### dplyr since 1.0.4

See https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/

```r
diamonds %>%
  filter(if_any(across(starts_with("c"),~grepl("^S" ,.))))
```