# How to filter for rows in a data frame that contain ANY of the values in a vector in ANY of the columns

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, grepl

I have been trying to use dplyr in R to filter a large data frame that has some empty (NA) cells in it. The string I want to use is a vector containing several alphanumeric search terms.

**My goal is to create a new data frame or tibble of the rows that contain ANY of the strings in the vector in ANY of the columns of the data frame.**

I have tried several things with a data frame I cannot share, but I found an answer in another question that *almost* does what I need, except for using a vector as the search term.

From [Filter rows which contain a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filter-rows-which-contain-a-certain-string) :

Filtering for rows where any column fulfils a condition

```
ggplot2::diamonds %>%
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ grepl('V',.))) %>%
  head()

#> # A tibble: 6 × 10
#>   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  0.23 Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#> 2  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
#> 3  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
#> 4  0.24 Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47
#> 5  0.26 Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53
#> 6  0.22 Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49
```

Instead of V as the search term, what if I wanted to filter for a match to ANY value in a vector?

```
vector1 <- c("V", "F", "G", "E")
```

Some things I tried on my own data frame that worked for one value but not when using the vector as a search term:

```
dfdiamonds <- as.dataframe (ggplot2::diamonds)

`your text`test1 <- dfdiamonds %>%
rowwise() %>%
filter(any(c_across(cols=everything()) %in% c(vector1)

test2<- for(item in vector1) {
  dfdiamonds %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    filter(any(c_across(cols=2) == item)) 
}

test3 <- filter(dfdiamonds, any(c_across(cols = everything()) %in% c(vector1)) 

#I tried grep for this one and it gave a result as a value rather than a data frame
matches <- unique (grep(paste(vector1,collapse="|"), 
                        dfdiamonds, value=TRUE))
```

Anyway, I'm at a loss. Any solution will do!

Comment: The other answers on your linked question show the answer: just create a regex for several [possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24821141/12647315), in your case `"V|F|G|E"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter rows which contain a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850026/filter-rows-which-contain-a-certain-string)

Comment: @starja, no, that doesn't answer my question because I needed the code to use a vector as the search term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
ggplot2::diamonds %>%
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ grepl(paste0(vector1, collapse = "|"),.))) %>%
  head()
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution in this case is probably:

```r
library(tidyverse)

vector1 <- c("V", "F", "G", "E")

diamonds %>%
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~ grepl(paste(vector1, collapse = "|"),.))) %>%
  head()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 10
#>   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43
#> 2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
#> 3  0.23 Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
#> 4  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
#> 5  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75
#> 6  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>